# Unit Testing Embedded Glassfish on Cloudbees

Tags: glassfish, cloudbees

My REST application loads an embedded Glassfish before executing TestNG tests (actually make HTTP connection to REST resources). My questions are:

1. If I build the application on Cloudbees, will Jenkins for CI work?
2. Will Jenkins still run embedded Glassfish over port 8080, and execute tests using the HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

you should not rely hard-coded port 8080 but use a dynamically assigned port (you can use jenkins [port allocator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin) plugin). Maven also can provide such a random free port using [build-helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/reserve-network-port-mojo.html) plugin if you use it for building.